Programmatically created NSWindow crashes upon close
I am trying to wrap my head around proper lifecycles of NSWindows and how to handle them properly.
I have the default macOS app template with a ViewController inside a window that is inside a Window Controller.
I also create a simple programatic window in applicationDidFinishLaunching like this:
let dummyWindow = CustomWindow(contentRect: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 200, height: 100)), styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .resizable], backing: .buffered, defer: true)
dummyWindow.title = "Code window"
dummyWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)

The CustomWindow class is just:
class CustomWindow: NSWindow {
    deinit {
        print("Deinitializing window...")
    }
}

When I close the programatic window (either by calling .close() or by just tapping the red close button, the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Even though I am not accessing the window in any way.
One might think it's because of ARC but it's not. One—the window is still strongly referenced by NSApplication.shared.windows even when the local scope of applicationDidFinishLaunching ends. And two—the "Deinitializing window..." is only printed after the window is closed.
Closing the Interface Builder window works without any crashes. I dug deep and played with the isReleasedWhenClosed property. It made no difference whether it was false or true for the IB window. It stopped the crashing for the programmatic window though.
But this raises three questions:

What is accessing the programatic window after it's closed—causing a crash because the default behaviour of NSWindow is to release it—if it's not my code?
What is the difference under the hood between a normal window and a window inside a window controller that prevents these crashes?
If the recommended approach for programmatic windows is to always set isReleasedWhenClosed = false then how do you actually release a programatic window so that it does not linger in memory indefinetely?


If the EXC_BAD_ACCESS means that an object is double de-allocated then that would mean that .close() both releases the window (first release) and removes it from the window list which would mean last strong reference is released and ARC cleans the window out (second release).
The theory is supported by me calling  .orderOut instead of close which only removes it from the application list and that does indeed release it without crash. Does this mean programmatic windows should override the close() instance method to call orderOut() instead?
This seems like poor API design.


1. What is accessing the programatic window after it's closed—causing a crash because the default behaviour of NSWindow is to release it—if it's not my code?

The backtrace of the crash shows that the window is referenced from the autorelease pool. The window has already been deallocated.

2. What is the difference under the hood between a normal window and a window inside a window controller that prevents these crashes?

From the documentation of isReleasedWhenClosed:

Release when closed, however, is ignored for windows owned by window controllers.

This means that a window owned by a window controller doesn't look at isReleasedWhenClosed and the window is not released when closed. The window controller owns and releases the window.

3. If the recommended approach for programmatic windows is to always set isReleasedWhenClosed = false then how do you actually release a programatic window so that it does not linger in memory indefinetely?

The recommended approach for programmatic windows is to set isReleasedWhenClosed to false so the window follows the ARC rules. If there are no strong references then the window will be deallocated. You can use NSWindowDelegate method windowWillClose(_:) or willCloseNotification to release the window in case you keep a strong reference.
AppKit retains windows. I think this is for backwards compatibility. This explains why the window doesn't disappear when dummyWindow goes out of scope and the window is released.

If your application is linked on macOS 10.13 SDK or later, NSWindows that are ordered-in will be strongly referenced by AppKit, until they are explicitly ordered-out or closed (not including hide or minimize operations). This means that, generally, an on-screen window will not be deallocated (and close/order-out as a side-effect of deallocation).

Source: AppKit Release Notes for macOS 10.13
A bit of history:
1. Objective-C and manual retain-release (MRR, before ARC)
When ARC didn't exist and we had to manually retain and release our objects, it was possible to create an instance and let it float in memory. There were no references to this object. This 'feature' was used for delegates and controllers that release themself or would exist untill the app quit. It also worked for windows. But then the window would leak when the user closes the window. Solution: set releasedWhenClosed to YES (default) and the window is automagically released when it is closed.
Example 1, window is not reused
- (void)showMyWindow {
    NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 500, 500)
        styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable
        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];   // retain count = 1
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

When the user closes the window, the window releases itself (releasedWhenClosed = true) (retain count = 0) and is deallocated.
Example 2, window is reused
ivar: NSWindow *myWindow
- (void)showMyWindow {
    if (!myWindow) {
        myWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 500, 500)
            styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable
            backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];   // retain count = 1
        [myWindow setReleasedWhenClosed:NO];
    }
    [myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

When the user closes the window, the window does not release itself (retain count = 1) and is not deallocated.
2. And then came ARC:
Example 1 with ARC:
- (void)showMyWindow {
    NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 500, 500)
        styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable
        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];   // retain count = 1
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    // window goes out of scope and is released (retain count = 0)
}

The window is deallocated immediately and disappears from the screen. A disappearing window is a problem so from OS X 10.13 the window is retained by AppKit while it is on screen.
- (void)showMyWindow {  // 10.13+
    NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 500, 500)
        styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable
        backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];   // retain count = 1
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]; // retained by AppKit, retain count = 2
    // window goes out of scope and is released, retain count = 1
}

When the user closes the window, AppKit releases the window (retain count = 0) and the window releases itself (releasedWhenClosed = true) (retain count = -1). The app crashes.
With ARC it is not possible to retain and not release a window so isReleasedWhenClosed should be false.
Note: The retain counts are not the value of retainCount, the window is retained and (auto)released many times by AppKit.

Thanks for the reply!


So the autorelease pool is trying to access the window to release it, only to find out it has already been released?


I read about that, but I was wondering, under the hood, why doesn't closing a window in a window controller crash if isReleasedWhenClosed is ignored? Does that imply this window is hardcoded to not released on close?


It makes sense that the best approach is to always set this to false (in the OP I switched true for false, sorry). How come this isn't explicitly mentioned somewhere? I feel like many people must have stumbled upon this.



And thanks for the AppKit release notes. This makes sense—AppKit retains windows. Everything onscreen is in the NSApplication.shared.windows array where there is a strong reference (therefore it is not released by ARC when dummyWindow reference goes out of scope).

NSApplication.shared.windows is a calculated property, the windows are retained somewhere else.

Thank you so much for taking the time to provide the historical context. It makes much more sense now! So much, in fact, I might write a blog post about it, give you credit and explain it thoroughly so that more people know about it.
Two questions:

You say "Window goes out of scope and is released, retain count 1" in the ARC example. I think 'released' is incorrect, as the retain count it still 1. Otherwise everything seems in check
How can we know windows is computed and not stored (with inaccessible setter) based on the NSApplication class definition alone?


Last ask: How do the windows inside window controller work? They respect ARC so I supposed isReleaseWhenClosed or some similar internal property is hardcoded to false? Or?


See release and Ownership Policy Is Implemented Using Retain Counts. window is released but not deallocated if it is retained by something else.



windows is a read-only property and it was a method before properties existed. To be sure I set a break on -[NSApplication windows] and I looked at what it did. If you want to see what's retaining a window, take a look at the Memory Graph Hierarchy.



Thanks. I misinterpreted release as dealloc. TIL.
You set a symbolic breakpoint and then read the symbol name from the assembly code objc_msgSend$_copyWindows? Which would maybe suggest it's copying the windows from somewhere else? Am I getting it right? Sorry for asking so much. I want to learn as much as possible.
It occurred to me to look at the memory graph but I am not quite sure if I am getting it right. There are many nodes—more than 1. e.g. 'malloc', NotificationCenter node. Many nodes pointing to the window  ..NSKVONotifying_WindowsTesting.CustomWindow.


I captured my screen to show the graph here: https://share.cleanshot.com/bh8rNLJZ. I would expect to only see NSApplication to be referencing the window but the graph says "20"?

You can set a break on -[NSWindow _copyWindows] or step into objc_msgSend$_copyWindows until you get there. There are so many nodes that I can't find where isReleasedWhenClosed is used or where AppKit retains and releases the window. Maybe a lot of the nodes are ivars that used to be weak and are now strong be default.

I don't mind follow-up questions at all. I'd rather answer questions from someone who wants to learn and understand than from someone who just wants to copy a piece of code.

Thanks. I didn't realise I can step into what seems like an atomic instruction at first glance! So where are the copied windows coming from? From NSApplicationHideNSMenuWindowManagerWindows? I don't see anything helpful from stepping into the copyWindows.

Were you unable to see what's retaining the window using the Memory Graph? Which makes sense as there is so many nodes and it's confusing. I would have expected just one node (one strong reference). Does the ivar hypothesis mean the retain count really is high (>20) and all of them get released once the time is right?


Take a look at the NSApplication Memory Graph, it has 2 strong ivars, _windowList, a NSConcretePointerArray and _openWindows, a NSConcreteHashTable. While stepping through _copyWindows, when the pc is at objc_msgSend$…, x0 is the receiver, x1 is the selector, x2.. are the arguments. Apparently _copyWindows  instantiates a NSMutableArray and calls countByEnumerating… on a NSConcretePointerArray with the same address as _windowList.

It looks like all views in the window have a strong _viewRoot ivar pointing at the window. This _viewRoot ivar didn't exist in 10.6 so it isn't not an old ivar that used to be weak. The old _window ivar still exists but doesn't show up in the memory graph.

When isReleasedWhenClosed is true, autorelease is called from -[NSWindow _finishClosingWindow]. I think the open windows are retained by _openWindows.

Thanks for going into detail. I am not sure what I am seeing in my graph. The only instance having  'NSApplication' in the name is NSKVONotifying_NSApplication and it has many ivars, not 2. See: https://share.cleanshot.com/2D4cc0zL
So I am not following along :/ The memory graph debugger still is a mystery to me.

A manual or documentation would be nice, but I can't find it. You'll have to experiment to find out how it works. To the right of the NSApplication node are the nodes that NSApplication is referencing, in this case 5 nodes. Select a node or line to see details. Click on the Mickey Mouse ears to expand the node or change the visible references. Right click, double click, press the Option-key, zoom in, explore.

Thank you Willeke! I just realised the references have names, the NSApplication has  _windowList array of pointers so I think it's safe to say this is the reference in NSApplication.shared.windows and this is what retains the  windows while they are on screen.
Thank you for your continued effort. I really appreciate it.

great great answer, and although I could fix my crash reading only the few first paragraphs - I'll pay attention to all the details.
However - I think for me it boils down to just one thing: call [win orderOut:sender]; before closing the window. The does the trick.
